# docker コンテナの Ubuntu 上で apt-get install を試みるも dependency エラーが発生してしまう

Tags: ubuntu, docker, apt

- Intel NUC Core i7-6770HQ搭載 小型PCベアボーン M.2 SSD対応 BOXNUC6I7KYK

が2台あり、どちらも CentOS 7.4.1708 をインストールして、Docker version 18.02.0-ce, build fc4de44 を動かしています。
ネットワークも同じネットワーク(IPは異なりますが)で、DNS設定も同一にしています。

```
docker pull ioft/i386-ubuntu:14.04.3
```

でUbuntu 14.04.3 LTSを持ってきて以下のコマンドでコンテナを動かしました。

```
docker run -d --restart=always -e LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8 --privileged \
    --name server1 -h server1 -v /ramdisk:/ramdisk -p 86:86 -p 10022:10022 \
    ioft/i386-ubuntu:14.04.3 /sbin/init
```

※ /ramdiskはRAMディスクを作成しています。

```
docker exec -it server1 bash
```

でコンテナに入り、opensshをインストールしようにも

```
root@server1:/# apt-get install openssh-server
パッケージリストを読み込んでいます... 完了
依存関係ツリーを作成しています 状態情報を読み取っています... 完了
以下の問題を解決するために 'apt-get -f install' を実行する必要があるかもしれません:
以下のパッケージには満たせない依存関係があります:
language-pack-ja : 依存: language-pack-ja-base (>= 1:14.04+20140410) しかし、インストールされようとしていません 
openssh-server : 依存: libck-connector0 (>= 0.2.1) しかし、インストールされようとしていません
                  依存: libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.10+dfsg~) しかし、インストールされようとしていません
                  依存: libkrb5-3 (>= 1.6.dfsg.2) しかし、インストールされようとしていません
                  依存: libwrap0 (>= 7.6-4~) しかし、インストールされようとしていません
                  依存: openssh-client (= 1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.10) しかし、インストールされようとしていません
                  依存: openssh-sftp-server しかし、インストールされようとしていません
                  推奨: xauth しかし、インストールされようとしていません
                  推奨: ncurses-term しかし、インストールされようとしていません
                  推奨: ssh-import-id しかし、インストールされようとしていません
E: 未解決の依存関係です。'apt-get -f install' を実行してみてください (または解法を明示してください)。
```

のエラーが発生します。

language-pack-ja-baseでもエラーになります。

```
root@server1:/# apt-get install language-pack-ja-base
パッケージリストを読み込んでいます... 完了 依存関係ツリーを作成しています 状態情報を読み取っています... 完了
以下の問題を解決するために 'apt-get -f install' を実行する必要があるかもしれません:
以下のパッケージには満たせない依存関係があります:  language-pack-ja-base : 依存:
language-pack-ja (>= 1:14.04+20160720) しかし、1:14.04+20140410 はインストールされようとしています
競合: language-pack-ja (< 1:14.04+20160720) しかし、1:14.04+20140410 はインストールされようとしています E: 未解決の依存関係です。
'apt-get -f install' を実行してみてください (または解法を明示してください)。
```

しかし、もう一つのNUCでapt-get installしたところ、問題なくインストールできます。
ハードもOSも同じ（と思う）なのですが、何が原因かお分かりになる方は是非ご教授お願いできればと思います。何卒よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ありきたりな確認ですが、`apt-get install`の前に`apt-get update`を実行してパッケージリストは更新されていますか。

Comment: はい。apt-get updateも実施しましたが状況変わりません。